# How can I abort a Javascript function at an arbitrary point in time

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js

I have a function that mutates some global state. How can I abort this function when a certain condition comes true in order to prevent a race condition. Here is a code sample to clarify.

```js
let globalState = 0
const mutateState = () => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        globalState = Math.random()
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mutateState()"></button>
```

In essence when the user clicks that button I need to cancel the previous call to mutateState function so that it doesn't alter the global state.

Also for context I am using Vuejs (not in this example though).

Putting an if statement before the globalState assignment is not ideal because in my real code I have a lot of variables and a lot of places in the code that they are mutated, it becomes tedious to put an if statement in front of each of them.

**Ideally I want a way to abort the function completely.**

Comment: You know… return and throw are two sure ways to terminate a function call.

Comment: where can I put the throw and return

Comment: For clarification, are there two functions which depend on each other here? mutateState() and mutateData()?

Comment: My mistake, I was referring to the same function, I've edited it for clarity

Comment: “ In essence when the user clicks that button I need to cancel the previous call to mutateState function so that it doesn't alter the global state.” so here you mean even a double click will be treated as just one click?

Comment: Exactly, in other words the side effects of any clicks in the past will not affect the value of globalState. Otherwise I might have the situation where the first click I did overrides the side effects of the second click I did.

Comment: What’s the time out for a double click? I mean if a double click takes place in 2ms then it’s definitely a double click. But one in a 5s interval isn’t one is it?

Comment: I am referring to a scenario where the browser detects two individual clicks

Comment: Please clarify, I didn’t quite catch that.

Comment: WebWorker may be useful in this case

Comment: Are you sure you don't want just throttle/debounce?

Comment: You preserve timeout id and call clearTimeout. If your real code doesn't use timeouts then post it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call [`clearTimeout(yourTimeoutId)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout) to cancel its callback:

```js
let globalState = 0
let timeoutId = null;
const mutateState = () => {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(()=> {
        globalState = Math.random()
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
}

const cancelMutate = () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer because this mainly depends on the context.

However, there is [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController), which can be used as a standardized way to abort a control flow. It doesn't do any magic that would automatically abort something, but APIs can use it to check if a process has to be aborted.

`fetch` is an example where it can be used:

```
  controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;
  fetch(url, { signal })
```

And with `controller.abort();` that fetch can be aborted.

You can use that controller also in your code:

```js
let globalState = 0
const mutateState = (() => {
  let abortController;

  return function() {
    abortController?.abort();

    abortController = new AbortController();

    setAbortableTimeout(() => {
        globalState = Math.random();
        
        console.log(abortController.signal.aborted);
        console.log(globalState);
        
      },
      Math.random() * 1000,
      abortController.signal);
  }
})()

function setAbortableTimeout(cb, time, signal) {
  let timer = setTimeout(cb, time);

  signal.addEventListener("abort", () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });

  return timer
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', mutateState);
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Either by checking if the state of `signal.aborted`, or using  `signal.addEventListener("abort", …)` to the abort event.

The above code is a simplified example, but I hope you understand how to use it.